# Going to meta.gaming.stackexchange.com redirects to non-meta login page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, login, meta, stackexchange-2.0

When I go to meta.gaming.stackexchange.com, I am redirected to the login page on gaming.stackexchange.com (the "**meta.**" has been dropped). After logging in, I am still in the non-meta site. I should have been redirected back to the meta site, since that's where I was trying to go.

Furthermore, I am on the non-meta login page, which makes it look like I haven't logged in (except for the fact that I now see my user name at the top of the screen).

Comment: +1 because this is also the case on Webmasters.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: fair enough, but is it possible to at least redirect to the home page after login? Leaving the user staring at the login page when they are already logged in is a little confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logins for both gaming and meta.gaming are tied together, somewhat. Here's what I've found:

- When you log in to one, you are logged in to both.
- When I log in to meta.gaming first, it first takes me to the login for gaming, then sends me back to meta.gaming after I log in.
- Logging out of gaming leaves you logged in to meta.gaming, but logging out of meta.gaming logs you out of *both*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember logging in to meta.gaming, I think I logged in to the main site and was magically logged in to meta.

Perhaps it doesn't have a log in per se.

Comment: correct, there is no "logging in" to child metas. See the faq on those sites.